# Delete a Customer Progmatically in Magento

Tags: php, magento

How can I delete a customer in magento by refering or using its object from `Mage::getModel("customer/customer")` ?

I already researched in google and with the bad luck I found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it out. customer is an EAV like products that can be deleted using `delete()` method.
Just flag the object to be deleteable using `$customer->setIsDeleteable(true)` because the customer model class which is `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer` implements `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` which contains the `delete()` method

I used the following codes below

```
$customer->loadByEmail('test@test.com');
$customer->setIsDeleteable(true);
$customer->delete();
```

if you want the deletion to workout in the frontend(in my case its backend) you need to initiate the `Mage::register('isSecureArea', true)`

Answer (score 1):

Please find the below solution

```
$sessCustomer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');        
$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
// load by customer id
$customer->load($sessCustomer->getId()); 
try {       
        Mage::register('isSecureArea', true);       
        $customer->delete();                            
    }catch (Exception $e){
        $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

        //current user delete using email
        $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
        Mage::register('isSecureArea', true);     
        $email = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getEmail();
        $customer->loadByEmail($email);
        $customer->setIsDeleteable(true);
        $customer->delete();

    ?>
```